# How to checkout changes from a shelve

Tags: tfs

Ref: tf command line

Assuming I added a bunch of code changes to a shelve 'foo' and
I have another copy (in a different machine) of the same source tree.

How I use the command 'tf shelf' to checkout my changes into the current source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all in the documentation:

[Working with Team Foundation Source Control from Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthc5x3f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Shelve Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6y8ezzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
tf shelve  [/replace] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)] [shelvesetname] [/validate][/noprompt] [/login:username,[password]]
```

[Unshelve Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6bx4df3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
tf unshelve [/move] [shelvesetname[;username]] itemspec 
[/recursive] [/noprompt]
```